# Create a symmetrical matrix from a sequence in Clojure

Tags: matrix, clojure

I have a sequence of integers:

```
(9 14 21 23 22 25 32 36 38 42)
```

Which represents the values from a lower triangular matrix:

```
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  9|  0|  0|  0|  0|
| 14| 21|  0|  0|  0|
| 23| 22| 25|  0|  0|
| 32| 36| 38| 42|  0|
```

I want to create a symmetrical matrix based on this sequence:

```
(( 0  9 14 23 32)
 ( 9  0 21 22 36)
 (14 21  0 25 38)
 (23 22 25  0 42)
 (32 36 38 42  0))
```

As I am relatively new to Clojure, this is what I could think so far (which seems very procedural):

```
(defn at
  "Equivalent to matrix[i][j]"
  [m i j]
  (nth (nth m i) j))

(defn group-inf-lines
  "Group each values from inferior lines of the matrix"
  [values n]
  (let [create-line
        (fn [line curr i n]
          (if (empty? curr)
               line
               (recur (conj line (take i curr))
                      (drop i curr)
                      (inc i)
                      n)))]
    (create-line [] values 1 n)))

(defn create-symmetrical-matrix
  "Take a sequence of values and create a symmetrical matrix of size n x n"
  [values n]
  (let [inf-lines (group-inf-lines values n)]
    (for [i (range n)]
      (for [j (range n)]
        (cond (> i j) (at inf-lines (dec i) j)
              (< i j) (at inf-lines (dec j) i)
              :else 0)))))
```

Is there a most Clojure-ist way to do it?
Solutions which use non-native features are also welcome (i.e. from libraries like clojure.core.matrix).

Comment: I updated the question with my solution

Answer (score 2):

the main thing which is really unidiomatic for clojure (and i guess any functional language) in your code, is counting on indices, while the task could be fulfilled using just collections processing. Here is one solution i came up with (obviously there could be more).

first of all i would make a triangle collection from the data:

```
(def data '(9 14 21 23 22 25 32 36 38 42))

(defn triangle [[x & xs :as data]]
  (when (seq data)
    (butlast
     (map first
          (reductions (fn [[_ snd] i]
                        (if (seq snd)
                          (split-at i snd)
                          (reduced nil)))
                      [[x] xs]
                      (iterate inc 2))))))

user> (triangle data)
;;=> ([9] (14 21) (23 22 25) (32 36 38 42))
```

the second step is to "transpose" the triangle, making the left half of the matrix:

```
(defn transpose-triangle [triangle]
  (->> triangle
       (iterate #(filter seq (map rest %)))
       (map (partial map first))
       (take-while seq)))

user> (transpose-triangle (triangle data))
;;=> ((9 14 23 32) (21 22 36) (25 38) (42))
```

and the last part is to "glue" the triangle with it's transposed version:

```
user> (let [tri (triangle data)
            ttri (transpose-triangle tri)]
        (map concat
             (cons nil tri)
             (repeat [0])
             (concat ttri [nil])))
;;=> ((0 9 14 23 32) 
;;    (9 0 21 22 36) 
;;    (14 21 0 25 38) 
;;    (23 22 25 0 42) 
;;    (32 36 38 42 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a quite interesting algorithm to implement:

```
(defn make-triangular [coll]
  (let [n-coll   (count coll)
        n-rows   (->> (range) (reductions +) (take-while #(<= % n-coll)) count)

        ; n-rows x n-rows matrix of zeros, needs to be a vector to support assoc:
        zeros    (mapv (comp vec repeat) (repeat n-rows n-rows) (repeat n-rows 0))]
    (->> coll
         (reduce
           (fn [[result [row col]] v]
             [; assoc v to upper and lower triangles:
              (-> result
                  (assoc-in [row col] v)
                  (assoc-in [col row] v))

              ; calculate where the next value should go:
              (if (= col (dec row))
                [(inc row) 0]            ; Approaching the diagonal, drop down by one row and reset to the first col
                [row       (inc col)])]) ; Not at diagonal yet, stay at the same row and move to the next col
           [zeros [1 0]]) ; Starting from a zero matrix, row 1 and col 0
         first))) ; Extract the result
```

I opted to use `reduce` and destructuring to keep track of "state", namely which location we are filling. A more "stream-oriented" could be more efficient approach, as this does `O(n^2)` assocs to a persistent vector.

The usage of `repeat` in `map` feels a bit hacky, but I've found it useful at code golf.